# Stretch text in a TextArea control in Flex 3

Tags: text, flex3, textarea, stretch

I think I might be missing something really obvious here but how can I stretch the width or height of the text in a TextArea rather than just resizing the bounding box of the control ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it is obvious - you must embed the Font in order to stretch it...